# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Stuck in Reboot Loop

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have an old Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 I dug up from many years ago. When I tried to turn it on after charging it fully, it was stuck in a reboot loop. I already tried factory resetting it and clearing the cash, but it hasn't helped. I am trying to flash an new OS using ODIN, but since I haven't been able to turn USB tethering on, I can't connect the tablet to my computer. Is there any way I can turn USB tethering on through the recovery mode, maybe through the ADB? Just to be clear, I can not access the settings before the tablet reboots itself, and I never turned on developer tools.

Comment: you don't need cash, tethering, usb-debugging/adb, developer options or recovery mode. just enter download mode and flash with Odin (it's free) https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-p5110-galaxy-tab-2-101/download-mode

Comment: when I enter download mode the tablet doesn't connect to the computer though, on device manager it keeps coming up as an unrecognized device. I downloaded the proper USB drivers off the Samsung website as well, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: if you can't install right drivers then use [heimdall](https://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall) for linux

Comment: how will that help if the tablet isn't connecting to the pc? I have the drivers, but my computer isn't recognizing the tablet? I'm also on Windows by the way

Comment: *"it keeps coming up as an unrecognized device"* sounds like a recognized connection to me. yes i know you are on windows, that's why i recommend linux. try Xubuntu LTS from bootable usb flash drive (press F11 or F12 before computer starts up for boot menu) https://unetbootin.github.io documentation [README](https://gitlab.com/BenjaminDobell/Heimdall/raw/master/Linux/README), 
[support](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755265),
[tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=878686) or search [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/97304)

Comment: it's not a recognized connection, Odin won't detect the device either. I want to know if it is still possible to flash new firmware without turning on USB tethering, since I'm not able to access the settings that would let me turn it on.

Comment: but i have other opinion. you can see a coming up (unrecognized) device each time when connecting phone? that is clearly some kind of reaction. and of course Odin won't detect anything without successful installed drivers. nevertheless, installing drivers is a windows thing. no need to install drivers on linux

Comment: It is the Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, model number GT-P5113. I'm trying to flash from SIM card if possible now, since my pc still isn't recognizing the device as a Galaxy Tab 2. I understand that it is a reaction, but it doesn't help. I tested my drivers with another Samsung device as well and it worked, so I don't think it is a problem with that either. I think it is either a problem with the cable or the device itself. My question now is how to properly flash from SIM if it is even possible.

Comment: indeed for this old device it is possible to boot (oem signed) custom recovery via update sdcard. try [philz_touch_6.57.8-p5110-signed.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2201860) and clean up */data/log* with [Aroma file manager](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215785

Comment: from custom recovery it should even possible to install ROM from adb shell, but this requires converting with simg2img (which is a linux tool) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219853

Comment: I'm running into a signature verification failed error when I try to install the zip you gave, I'm not sure if it isn't OEM signed or if there is some other problem, but it's not letting me install the custom recovery, and most resources online say I need one in order to flash anything. Is there anyway to sign the zip or bypass the signature check through stock recovery?

Comment: if your usb-connector is broken, you can try to sign zip with test keys. i recommend to mention [@osm0sis](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=56852382&postcount=189) in proper [xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2202635) (it's not his project but he is still active member and has the knowledge) otherwise it would be easier to flash TWRP from linux

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226261