# Android doesn't ask USB usage when connecting to Windows, works on Linux

Tags: usb-connection-mode, data-transfer

Just out of the blue, my phone suddenly stopped asking permission to access storage. It worked yesterday. When I connect the phone with the same cable to Linux PC it works but Windows keeps telling USB device not recognized and I don't get a popup in Android asking for USB permission. There is also nothing in the notifications on Android.

I tried to disable always ask but it still won't show up. How can I make my phone always answering as a mass storage?

Comment: If it works with Linux and does not work with Windows, then the cause is most likely not on Android side. Check the Windows device manager if the Android MTP device is recognized at all and without exclamation mark.

Comment: It says "unknown device, try reconnecting the device if windows still doesn't recognize replace the device"....

Comment: Try uninstall USB drivers, re-install, reboot windows with device disconnected - usually this seems to help

Comment: I never installed any USB drivers..?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the device model, but Windows usually need OEM USB drivers to recognize the device. Further reading: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb